# С чего начать изучение литературы по написанию игр

Tags: java, c#, c++, разработка-игр

Хочу научиться делать браузерные игры. В гугле я нашел целую гору литературы, но когда начинаю ее читать, становится ясно, что в большинстве книг даются просто примеры по написанию конкретных простых игр. При этом сами основы функционирования каких-либо методов и классов вообще не затрагиваются.

Пожалуйста, подскажите какую литературу стоит почитать в первую очередь. Интересуют [java](/questions/tagged/java), [с++](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%2b%2b), [с#](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%23).

Comment: Со всем уважением, к сожалению я не вижу способа перефразировать вопрос так, что бы можно было дать однозначный ответ на него. Учитывая направленность сайта, думаю этот вопрос будет интересен не только мне, но и многим другим начинающим. Очень прошу Вас не закрывать его.

Answer (score 7):

По-моему, очевидно, что читать нужно учебники по этим языкам. Чтобы писать код, нужно "говорить" на этом языке, а *что* это будет за код - игра, приложение, библиотека - это уже другой вопрос, который нужно решать (и углублять знания в данной области), владея основами. По Java классически рекомендуется начать с Эккеля  "Философия Java".

Если вы собрались изучать сразу три языка, то, скорее всего, у вас ничего не получится ни с одним из них. Выберите один и работайте с ним, когда освоите в достаточной степени, чтобы писать собственный код, попробуйте другой. Из перспективы создания десктопных игр начать лучше, скорее всего, с C#, для браузерных, как правило, используется Java.

Зная C# будет несложно освоить Java (или наоборот), так как они во многом схожи.

С++ это совсем другой уровень и лежит он несколько в другой плоскости, чем Java и C#, если вы решите разрабатывать на этом языке, то, скорее всего, все время уйдет на его освоение, а накопленный опыт будет во многом бесполезен в изучении Java и C#, а также разработки на этих языках.

Замечу (это мое мнение не претендующее на истинность), что в наше время использовать С++ во многих случаях нет необходимости. По скорости выполнения кода языки с виртуальной машиной практически не уступают нативным, а по "удобству" написания кода во много превосходят, к тому же имеют большое количество уже готовых библиотек.

Comment: Спасибо большое за Ваш ответ. В данный момент я пишу на java. С++ знаю слабо, но приходилось писать и на нем тоже. С# не знаю вообще.  Интересуют именно браузерные игры. Философию Java читал. Основы языка понял. Вот только никак не могу найти хороший мануал именно по графическим библиотекам. Не могли бы Вы посоветовать что-либо?

Comment: а как вы считаете, может стоит изучать _фреймворк_ а не язык. К примеру `Unity` и `C#` не сильно связаны.

Answer (score 1):

Браузерной - значит на 95% ваш управляющий код будет на JavaScript, лишь только для серверной части упомянутые вами Java, С++, С#

Хочу заметить, если в браузерной игре будет задействована трехмерная графика, то неплохо ознакомится с основами трехмерной графики, принципами работы графического конвеера и вообще [WebGL](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API) ибо там "своя атмосфера", вот довольно-таки неплохо WebGL фреймворк [three.js](http://threejs.org/examples/), точнее примеры написанные с помощью него.

Comment: Большое спасибо за Ваш ответ. Обязательно прочту все что Вы посоветовали.